# Recursive list predicate in prolog

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

I'm having difficulty with my assignment, I have to write 2 predicates:

`remove_all/3` which removes all instances of a given element out of a list and output the list without the given variable, e.g.:

```
remove_all(a, [b,a,c,a,d], X)
```

gives

```
X = [b,c,d])
```

and

`remove_list/3` which removes all elements of a given list out of another list and outputs the resulting list, e.g.:

```
remove_list([a,b], [b,a,c,a,d], X)
```

gives

```
X=[c,d].
```

This is what I have:

```
remove_all(Rema,[],[]).
remove_all(Rema,[Rema|X],Res) :- 
    remove_all(Rema,X,Res).
remove_all(Rema,[L|P],Res) :- 
    remove_all(Rema,P,NR), Res=[L|NR].

remove_list([],ListB, ListRes).
remove_list([H|Taila],ListB,ListRes) :- 
    member(H,ListB), 
    remove_all(H,ListB,ListRes),
    remove_list(Taila,ListRes,ListRes) .

remove_list([S|Tailb],ListB,ListRes) :- 
    remove_list(Tailb, ListB, ListRes).
```

Now, my `remove_all` works fine, but not when I use it in my `remove_list` predicate, it will then only remove all the instances of the first element of the list which specifies which element are to be removed, for example:

```
?- remove_list([1,2],[1,2,3,2,1],F).
F = [2, 3, 2]
```

It only removes the 1's.

Anybody have any idea what to do?

Comment: In Prolog you define rules. So the rule `remove_list([],ListB, ListRes)` says that if you remove `[]` from any list `ListB` you can get any *other* list you want, `ListRes`. Does that sound correct? If you remove element of `[]` from `ListB`, what should that look like?

Comment: `remove_all/3` works fine: `remove_all(a,[a],[a]).` succeeds, that is not fine